# removing {} characters with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, mv

the problem is, that i cant remove the symbols { and } from strings in HTML files, inside the file the string looks like

```
Var @footer Set @footer = TransformXML(XML, GetPortfolioItem("Footer_EN_${et.mode}"))
```

and i need to remove ${et.mode} with the "newmode"  text var.
for example

```
was ("Footer_EN_${et.mode}"))
will be ("Footer_EN_my_current_mode"))
```

i set a var like the next one

```
echo -n "choose name: "
read newmode
path=/root/EN
newpath=tmp/EN_$newmode
default_text="${et.mode}"

sed -i "s/\/{et.mode}/\/$newmode/g" *.html
sed -i "s/$default_text/$newmode/g" *.html
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: Why do you have `\/` in the regexp? There's no backslash in the file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/18356

Comment: @shoover What does that question have to do with it? He's matching a programming language, not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sed -i 's/\${et\.mode}/'"$newmode/g" *.html
```

You need to match the `$` character literally, so it needs to be escaped. That should be done inside single quotes. The `$newmode` variable should be inside double quotes so it gets expanded.

Comment: As usual in these situations it's worth mentioning that `$newmode` shouldn't contain things like ampersands, backslashes, etc.